# Customize medusa gauge skin to make structure as (attached 1st image)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gauge

I have tried to make scene using gauge as below

[image: required_scene]

```
GaugeBuilder stepBuilder = GaugeBuilder.create().skinType(SkinType.DASHBOARD) ;
Gauge steps = stepBuilder.decimals(0).maxValue(850).unit("M").build();
steps.setSkin(new KpiSkin(steps));
```

Its giving me scene like below not as required scene.

[image: code_generated_scene]

And also the added value **850** for max value does not take it as max value (its rounded off value to 900).

Please help me with this, I am new with gauge implementation in JavaFx.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[Medusa gauges](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/wiki/Gauge-Skins) are made using pre-built skins, therefore each and every skins have uniquely supported attributes (few of them are common for all) 
As a example [IndicatorSkin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/raw/master/images/IndicatorSkin.png?raw=true) have a pointy needle and [KpiSkin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/raw/master/images/KpiSkin.png?raw=true) have square type needle, therefore you cant have pointy needle in [KpiSkin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/raw/master/images/KpiSkin.png?raw=true) (sadly that's one of  your main requirement).  Also in your requirements, you have three threshold areas (red, yellow,green) , but [KpiSkin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/raw/master/images/KpiSkin.png?raw=true) doesn't support thresholds at all , By the way [IndicatorSkin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/raw/master/images/IndicatorSkin.png?raw=true) supports one threshold value, not three :( Also max value always rounding to nearest hundredth value and you can't show the exact value either.

After considering all the supported attributes, maximum you can achieve some thing like this. (using KpiSkin)

[image]

**Not promising enough right ? sadly that's the ultimate truth**

If i were you, i would create my own custom gauge using `Label` with some custom painting , but that takes time for novice programmer. so i would sujjest you to go with [existing Skin](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa/blob/master/Overview.png?raw=true) in Medusa gauges or go for alternate library like [jfxtras](http://jfxtras.org/)

Comment: Thank u for explaining good, I have tried **medusa** almost all the way but none skintype seems to be enough :( 
Could u please suggest me some library (I included jfxtras) like **medusa** through which I can get it, as I need to make another scene which contain two indicator stick inside semicircle (does not require pointed needle).

Comment: @V.Dev Apart from medusa & jfxtras , even i dint find any good library. anyway check [this](https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2012/06/jfxtras-series-radial-gauge.html) out